# Tensorboard on Google Colab returns a link but doesn't do anything

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, google-colaboratory, tensorboard, object-detection-api

I have been using Google Colab for Object Detection using Tensorflow API and at this point, the model is already being trained.
I need to view the Tensorboard for the training going on.

This is the training call:

```
!python 'Object Detection/models/research/object_detection/legacy/train.py' --logtostderr --train_dir='Object Detection/Model'/ --pipeline_config_path='Object Detection/Faster_RCNN.config'
```

I have tried the following commands and these are their results:

1. `!tensorboard --logdir='Object Detection/Model'`

   > `TensorBoard 1.15.0 at http://cca84e64bb22:6006/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)`
2. `%tensorboard --logdir='Object Detection/Model'`

   > It showed `Launching Tensorboard...` for a couple secs and ended
3. `%load_ext tensorboard`

   > `The tensorboard extension is already loaded. To reload it, use:
   >   %reload_ext tensorboard`
4. `%reload_ext tensorboard`

   > Blank - No Output
5. I found this from 'tensorboard_in_notebooks.ipynb'

```
from tensorboard import notebook
notebook.list()
notebook.display(port=6006, height=1000)
```

> `Known TensorBoard instances:
>     - port 6006: logdir /Object Detection/Model (started 0:07:12 ago; pid 795)
>   Selecting TensorBoard with logdir Object Detection/Model (started 0:07:12 ago; port 6006, pid 795).`

6. ```
   LOG_DIR = 'Object Detection/Model'
   get_ipython().system_raw(
       'tensorboard --logdir {} --host 0.0.0.0 --port 6006 &'
       .format(LOG_DIR)
   )
   # Install
   ! npm install -g localtunnel

   # Tunnel port 6006 (TensorBoard assumed running)
   get_ipython().system_raw('lt --port 6006 >> url.txt 2>&1 &')

   # Get url
   ! cat url.txt
   ```

> `/tools/node/bin/lt -> /tools/node/lib/node_modules/localtunnel/bin/lt.js
>   + localtunnel@2.0.0
>   updated 1 package in 1.601s`
>
> The url.txt file created is empty

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
!tensorboard --logdir='Object Detection/Model'
```

with

```
%tensorboard --logdir='Object Detection/Model'
```